# TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)

Tags: kubuntu, firmware

I just got this error after a restart. I just don't know how to deal with it, been searching for solutions, but nothing seems to work. I'm using Kubuntu 17.10

Comment: I looked into that the first time I searched for the problem, but when I run the command, it says: "sh: sudo: not found". I saw someone else there having the same problem, though it wasn't answered unfortunately.

Comment: Try that line as `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/apt-get install intel-microcode`.  If that works, you might have a path issue.