# TSC_DEADLINE error when booting from live 18.04

Tags: live-usb, 18.04

I got `TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)` when trying to boot into a live session with a newly written Ubuntu 18.04 live USB (created with the 18.04 Startup Disk Creator).

A few days ago I upgraded the installed version on the same PC from 17.10 to 18.04 without problems.

Following the advice in [this question's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022024/tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata-please-update-microcode-to-version-0xb2-o) I did

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is my ISO correct? I couldn´t find the expected md5sum value on the Ubuntu server, here is what I got for my download:

```
129292a182136a35e1f89c586dbac2e2  ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Can someone confirm that this is correct?

Following the quoted error there were more coming:
[image: more errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded again the iso file and got the same md5sum, so the download was correct. I then wrote the downloaded file again to the same USB stick, with the same tool, the 18.04 Startup Disk Creator. And now it worked!

In the syslog file I can now see the same error message concerning `TSC_DEADLINE`, but the boot continues. So it looks that the first messages in the picture were not relevant, only those beginning with `SQUASHFS error:`, indicating that the first writing to the USB stick somehow failed.